# highcharts tooltip formatter: how to access adjacent points

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart with cumulative values. What I try to do in tooltip: show value of ( current point.y - previous point.y ). But I don't
know how to get the y value of the previous point in a tooltip formatter function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loop over each point in current serie and compare current point with loop point. If are the same, then extract point with index-1 from array of points.

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
                var x = this.point.x,
                    y = this.y,
                series = this.series,
                each = Highcharts.each,
                txt = 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';

             each(series.data, function(p, i){
                if(p.x === x && series.data[i-1]) {
                    txt += ' Previous: ' + series.data[i-1].y;
                }
             });

            return txt;
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3qw6ry06/

Comment: Thanks. Found a simpler answer from a similar question here.